# ssh key gets unexpectedly transfered to my own computer

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-agent

I have a development machine "Laptop" and here I have an SSH key for my git account in Bitbucket. I also have a production server "Server" where I do not want to use this key, instead I want to use another key with read-only permissions in Bitbucket.

My expected workflow was to use SSH to log onto Server and there I would run `git pull`. It works just fine. However, when I log out and try to do `git push` from Laptop, the push is rejected because I don't have write permissions. Using `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vv" git push` and `ssh-add -l`, I have found out, that if I add the read-only SSH key on the server, it also appears on my Laptop, so when I push, the read-only key is used. When I remove it from Laptop using `ssh-add -D` it is no longer available on Server either. So it seems that when I am logged to Server, the SSH agent always uses my Laptop configuration.

How can I prevent this? When I am logged to Server, I want to use Server's read-only ssh key, when I am on Laptop, I want to use my personal's ssh key.

I tried changing `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` to include

```
Host bitbucket.org
    ForwardAgent no
```

but it doesn't help me.

I tried looking for other questions but everyone has the opposite issue and they are trying to sync the keys instead, so I couldn't find an answer.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Have you tried `IdentityFile /path/to/key` ? By the way, you should NOT update `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, `~/.ssh/config` is a better option. And you should have a different config on server or laptop.

Comment: @Calumah Thank you, `IdentityFile` is the right option to change! I did not originally update `~/.ssh/config` because it did not exist yet, so I created it. Thank you for that as well. You should change the comment to an answer!

Comment: So I looked more into it and for some reason, I've been taught to connect to the server with `ssh -A ...` which is why the key was transferred to my Laptop when added to the ssh agent. Without using `-A` option and adding the key only then also solves the problem. 

Comment: Here you go for answer ;) Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `IdentityFile /path/to/key` ?

By the way, you should NOT update `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, creating a `~/.ssh/config` is a better option (and recommanded).

Also you should have a different config on "Server" and "Laptop".